# what is difference between namespace, package and module in perl?

Tags: perl

Namespace or package are same? I use Perl where we only have packages. I know there are other programming languages that also include modules.

What's the difference?

Comment: i suppose, that you should read [Camel Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_Perl) . It will reveal many interest features of Perl

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Namespace` is a general computing term meaning a container for a distinct set of identifiers. The same identifier can appear independently in different namespaces and refer to different objects, and a fully-qualified identifier which unambiguously identifies an object consists of the namespace plus the identifier.

Perl implements namespaces using the [`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) keyword.

A Perl *module* is a different thing altogether. It is a piece of Perl code that can be incorporated into any program with the `use` keyword. The filename should end with `.pm` - for **P**erl **M**odule - and the code it contains should have a `package` statement using a package name that is equivalent to the file's name, including its path. For instance, a module written in a file called `My/Useful/Module.pm` should have a `package` statement like `package My::Useful::Module`.

What you may have been thinking of is a *class* which, again, is a general computing term, this time meaning a type of object-oriented data. Perl uses its packages as class names, and an object-oriented module will have a *constructor* subroutine - usually called `new` - that will return a reference to data that has been [`blessed`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) to make it behave in an object-oriented fashion. By no means all Perl modules are object-oriented ones: some can be simple libraries of subroutines.

Answer (score 18):

The `package` directive sets the namespace. As such, the namespace is also called the package.

Perl doesn't have a formal definition of module. There's a lot of variance, but the following holds for a huge majority of modules:

- A file with a `.pm` extension.
- The file contains a single `package` declaration that covers the entirety of the code. (But see below.)
- The file is named based on the namespace named by that `package`.
- The file is expected to return a true value when executed.
- The file is expected to be executed no more than once per interpreter.

It's not uncommon to encounter `.pm` files with multiple packages. Whether that's a single module, multiple modules or both is up for debate.