# Difference Between Module and Package using Perl?

Tags: perl, module, package

As I try the below code for `package` using Perl I am not clear on the difference between `package` and module

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl -w

$i = 1; print "$i\n"; # Prints "1"

package foo;
$i = 2; print "$i\n"; # Prints "2"

package main;
print "$i\n"; # Prints "1"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190483/what-is-difference-between-namespace-package-and-module-in-perl

Comment: Where have you seen “module” used? It isn't a Perl language word

Comment: @Borodin Please correct me if i am wrong. In the above link you explained perl module and here you are saying it isn't perl language word.

Comment: That's correct. A Perl module is a source file that is written according to a collection of conventions. It uses the `package` language word, but `module` isn't a reserved word itself

Comment: @Borodin ooh now i get it. I thought it otherwise.

Comment: Maybe we should say a *keyword* or a *built-in*. The term *language word* is a bit confusing. :)

Answer (score 0):

A perl module (.pm file) is a container for one or more packages.  Whilst they can contain multiple packages, the general convention is one package per module.  The naming structure is then nicely mirrored, as in:

- lib/Some/Package/Path.pm
- package Some::Package::Path;